# file in res folder not recognized

Tags: android, eclipse, graphics, bitmapdata

I'm a pretty newbie programmer and am trying to draw a sprite on the screen using a `.png` file. I've gotten this to work before, it's not supposed to be difficult!  But I get an error for the following line:

```
Bitmap goodBearBit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.goodbear);
```

(Okay, the sprite is a teddy bear...I'm trying to get programming to appeal to my daughter...)

Eclipse says that 'goodbear' cannot be resolved or is not a field. I know resource names are supposed to be lower case, so this should work.  I've tried different names.  I've put copies of goodbear.png in all the drawable folders (hi/lo/med dpi).  Am I forgetting something obvious?(probably)  Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: As per your line code its should be worked, if your goodbear named .png file lies on drawable folder.

Comment: i know that it is weird, but if you are absolutely sure you have your image in the correct folder(s), you might try to delete R.java file and rebuild it (it should do this automatically, if not just do some clean/build manually) it worked for me

Comment: Hi.  Thanks.  Yes I'd heard about the delete R.java trick and I tried that.  Also tried 'clean.'  This is so frustrating.  I've tried different filenames, tried icon.png.  Should a resource-accessing line like this depend on anything elsewhere in the program, that I may have screwed up?

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap goodBearBit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.goodbear);
```

use this one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried your way but it still doesn't like the name of the file.  Same message.  The Eclipse window says a quick fix is to migrate the Android code.  Is this some sort of version problem?